# Exclude all sub categories from wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've been searching high and low for and answer to this, but I'm not actually sure it's possible!

I have a WP_Query that pulls posts from almost everything, however, I wish to exclude a specific category and/or all it's sub categories.

Searching around people are yet to find a solution for this.

Here's my query so far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
    'cat' => -98,
    'orderby' => 'desc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

I thought just excluding `cat 98` would grab all the sub categories too, but apparently not.

I've tried using:

`category__not_in`, `depth=0`, `parent=0` and even [an adaptation of this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-all-child-categories-of-a-category-from-showing-up-in-the-loop), with no luck.

Any ideas?

[EDIT]
I'm using a custom taxonomy called Collections, so putting `'collection' => 'vip'` into the query means it will only show this collection. I'm thinking if there's a way of reversing this so it excludes the collection instead?

As it's not possible to list all of the categories that will appear here as they will be changing all of the time.

[EDIT 2]
After the discussion in the comments below, here's the updated code.

```
$ex = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'collection',
    'child_of' => 98,
    'hide_empty' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories($ex);

$categoriesToExclude = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoriesToExclude[] = $category->cat_ID;
}

echo('<pre>'); var_dump($categories);


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
    'category__not_in' => $categoriesToExclude,
    'orderby' => 'desc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
); ?>

<?php echo('<br /><pre>'); var_dump($args); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So!

It appears I was trying to do the impossible. I couldn't get this script working for the life of me. So I tried a different angle. Instead of excluding a custom taxonomy and its terms, I decided to move all of my other terms into a parent term and just called that instead.

Here's the code if anyone's interested...

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;               

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
    'taxonomy' => 'collection',
    'term' => 'clubs',
    'orderby' => 'desc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);


$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would get the list of all sub categories with [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and then build a `'cat'` exclusion array based on the results.

```
$args = array('parent' => 98);
$categories = get_categories($args);

$categoriesToExclude = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categoriesToExclude[] = $category->cat_ID;
}


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
    'category__not_in' => $categoriesToExclude,
    'orderby' => 'desc',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

This is just an example, you may have to modify it slightly to fit your needs.

Comment: Would the fact my categories are custom taxonomies affect this in any way? Doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: What do you get in the `$categoriesToExclude` array? Maybe you need to specify a type or something in `get_categories()`, not sure. See the docs for `get_categories()`.

Comment: Yea just checked this, adding in 'taxonomy' => 'collection' to the $args doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: What does `get_categories($args)` return then? Use `print_r($categories)` to debug.

Comment: Ah! Semicolon was missing from your `$categories = get_categories($args)`

Comment: Hehe, fixed;) If you'd told me that you got a 500 error I would've seen it. Does it work now?

Comment: Page shows, still struggling to find the right thing to exclude it though. Looking through the `print_r` to see why it's not excluding

Comment: printing the arguments from the wp_query itself shows that the `category__not_in` argument returns the corrent ID's and should be excluding them, it just doesn't for some reason :/

Comment: Sounds fishy :\ Not sure I can do anything more without additional information. Maybe you could update the question to include all your current code. Including the loop after the query and where your code is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own function in order to exclude subcategory posts from the loop, using tips from the above post and elsewhere.

In my theme archive.php file, above the loop, I list the subcategories (optional):

```
    <?php
       $current_cat = get_queried_object();

       $args = array( 'parent'=>$current_cat->term_id, 'child_of' => $current_cat->term_id, );
        $categories = get_categories( $args );
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>

           <h2><?php echo $category->name ;?></h2>
           <p> etc....</p>
      <?php } ?>
```

In my functions.php file, I've added the following custom function using pre_get_posts:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'main_query_without_subcategory_posts' );

function main_query_without_subcategory_posts( $query ) {

if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // Not a query for an admin page.
    // It's the main query for a front end page of your site.

    if ( is_category() ) {

   //Get the current category
        $current_category = get_queried_object();
        //get the id of the current category
        $current_cat_id = $current_category->term_id;

        //find the children of current category
        $cat_args = array( 'parent'=>$current_category->term_id, 'child_of' => $current_category->term_id, );
        $subcategories = get_categories( $cat_args );

        //Get a list of subcategory ids, stick a minus sign in front
        $subcat_id = array();         
        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) { 
            $subcat_id[] = " -". $subcategory->term_id; 
        }

        //join them together as a string with a comma seperator          
        $excludesubcatlist = join(',', $subcat_id);

       //If you have multiple parameters, use $query->set multiple times
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
        $query->set( 'cat', ''.$current_cat_id.','.$excludesubcatlist.'' );
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in the archive.php, below the subcategories, I've added the regular WordPress loop which is now being modified by the above function:

```
<?php  while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
     <p> etc....</p>
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Though the WordPress codex says that using "category__in" will exclude posts from subcategories, that didn't work for me and subcategory posts were still showing.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/